# Need a wiring diagram for separate switches to a ceiling fan/light

Tags: electrical, switch, ceiling-fan, light

Anyone have a wiring diagram for converting a single switch that controls a ceiling fan/light kit into 2 separate switches that control each separately?  Power is at the switch and is in the middle of the run.  I currently have 12/2 from the switch to the kit, but I have the ability to change to 12/3 if that is easier.

Comment: Where does power come into it?  2 cables at the fan or only 1?

Comment: Power comes in at the switch.  The switch is in the middle of the run.  From switch to light/fan it is 12/2 (B/W/Copper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need 3 wires - switched hot fan, switched hot light, neutral, so you will have to replace the 12/2 with 12/3.

In the switch box, you should have:

- Incoming power = black hot/white neutral
- Outgoing (new 12/3) = black switched hot 1, red switched hot 2, white neutral

If you have two separate switches, connect the incoming hot to *both* switches by connecting two short pieces of black wire (pigtails) to the incoming hot and the other end of each pigtail to a switch. If you have a double switch with a "common" hot screw, connect the incoming hot directly to the "common" screw.

Connect the black switched hot wire to one switch.

Connect the red switched hot wire to the other switch.

Connect the two white neutral wires together.

In the ceiling box:

Connect the white neutral wire to the fan/light neutral. If there are two separate neutral connections, connect it to both of them using pigtails.

Connect the black switched hot to one of the hot connections (almost always at least one will be black, so use that one).

Connect the red switched hot to the other hot connection (usually either blue or red).

All grounds in each location are connected together.

Comment: That’s exactly what I was planning, also wanted to make sure that was to code.  Thanks for the help!